# Is my solution correct? (Integration in two variables)

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_A \frac{1}{1+2y}\ \text{d}x\text{d}y$$

Where $A$ is the triangle with vertexes $(1, 0)$, $(0, 2)$, $(1, 2)$

*Solution*

So I first of all drew the points on a plane, and then I understood that $x\in (0, 1)$ whereas I have to find the bounds for $y = f(x)$. For that reason, I obtained the line through $A$ and $B$:

$$y = -2x + 2$$

Hence $$A = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\ 0 \leq y \leq -2x + 2,\ 0\leq x \leq 1\}$$

So then

$$\int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{-2x + 2} \frac{\text{d}y}{1+2y}$$

The $y$ integral gives $\frac{1}{2}\ln\vert 1 + 2y\vert$ which evaluated at the boundaries reads $\frac{1}{2}\ln\vert 5x-4\vert$.

I'm ok since $5x-4 = 0 \iff x = 5/4$ which is out from the path of integration over $x$.

So

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \ln\vert 5x-4\vert $$

A change of variable $5x - 4 = u$ yields

$$\frac{1}{8}\int_1^5 \ln\vert t\vert \text{d}x = \frac{1}{8}(5\ln(5) - 4)$$

Is this all right?

Thank you!

Comment: Your bounds of integration are not correct. Draw the region and consider what should be the lower vs upper bound.

Comment: Also, it would save you some work to do the integral w.r.t. $x$ first.

Comment: @NinadMunshi In what sense they are wrong? Wrong order or wrong expression? $y$ runs from $0$ to $2$ along the straight line $-2x + 2$, when $x$ runs from $1$ to $0$. So I guess I have to exchange the $x$ bounds. 
If there is anything else wrong, then I don't see it...

Comment: Have you drawn the region? It doesn't sound like you did from your description.

Comment: It's a right triangle, and the hypothenuse is contained in the straight line $y = -2x + 2$. $x$ runs from $0$ to $1$ whereas $y$ follows that straight line above. I don't get where I am wrong

Comment: Please make subject lines informative as to the  mathematical content of the post, to facilitate future searches; don't make them about yourself and your current status of confusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry, I will write less about my status. So is my solution wrong? Why?

Comment: Isn't $-2x+2 \le y \le 2$?

Comment: Your misunderstanding is geometric - the inner bounds of a double integral are not points but curves. What you are claiming is that the triangle is bounded by the *lines* $y=-2x+2$ and $y=0$ (does this look right?). If that is not correct, what are the true bounds? And lastly, if you were to do the bounds with the $x$ integral first, what would those be?