# Where am I wrong (integration in two variables)

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am really stuck about this problem: an integral over a triangle.

I have to calculate

$$\int_T x y^2 \text{d}x \text{d}y$$

where $T$ is the triangle of vertexes $(-1, 0)$, $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.
I drew the triangle and it's a symmetric triangle.

The left side (the left part of the total triangle) is such that $x$ runs from $-1$ to $0$, while $y$ runs from $0$ to $x+1$, so this suggests

$$\int_{-1}^0 \text{d}x \int_0^{x+1} x y^2 \text{d}y =  \int_{-1}^0 x \frac{(x+1)^3}{3} \text{d}x = -\frac{1}{60}$$

The result in the notes says $\frac{1}{10}$.
I don't really get where I am wrong.

I also tried to calculate the two integrals separately but I obtain the same.

**EDIT**

Calculating the integral over the right side triangle, I observe $x$ runs from $0$ to $1$ whilst $y$ runs along $1-x$ straight line:

$$\int_0^1 x \text{d}x \int_{1-x}^0 y^2 \text{d}y = -\frac{1}{60}$$

I'm stuck.

Comment: Please make subject lines informative about the mathematical content of your post, to facilitate future searching, rather than about you.

Comment: The triangle is symmetric about the $y$ axis, but the function you are integrating is not: if you replace $x$ with $-x$, you do not have the same value of the function, so you cannot just calculate the integral along one triangle and then double.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, that is true indeed... I will calculate again the second integral, but as I said, I got the same result...

Comment: From $0$ to $1$, the inner integral goes from $0$ to $1-x$, not from $1-x$ to $0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That would give me zero then, in the end...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know it's off topic, but if you have time and will, could you please tell me why I am wrong about this too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695186/is-my-solution-correct-integration-in-two-variables?noredirect=1#comment9934725_4695186

Comment: Yes, you will get zero, because you *should* get zero. Your function takes opposite sign values at $(x,y)$ and at $(-x,y)$, and you are integrating along a region that is symmetric about the $y$ axis. Why wouldn't you get zero?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, thinking of it and making a parallelism with the integration in $\mathbb{R}$, is sounded logical to get zero (after having understood the error of not doubling the integration). Though you know, it's the problem of having the results in the notes: I got biased and I stopped reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just calculate the integral on half the region and double, because the integrand is not symmetric about the $y$ axis.

In fact, because the value at $(x,y)$ is the opposite sign from the value at $(-x,y)$, and you are integrating along a region symmetric about the $y$-axis, you should expect the integral to be zero, which in fact it is.

You have
$$\begin{align*}
\iint_T xy^2\,dx\,dy &= \int_{-1}^0\int_0^{x+1} xy^2\,dy\,dx + \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}xy^2\,dy\,dx\\
&= \int_{-1}^0 \frac{x(x+1)^3}{3}\,dx + \int_0^1\frac{x(1-x)^3}{3}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{-1}^0(x^4+3x^3+3x^2+x)\,dx + \int_0^1(x - 3x^2 + 3x^3 - x^4)\,dx\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{3}{4} + 1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - 1 +\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\right) = 0.
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively, you could integrate first with respect to $x$; the values of $y$ range from $0$ to $1$, and the values of $x$ range from the line $x=y-1$ to the line $x=1-y$, so we have
$$\begin{align*}
\iint_T xy^2\,dx\,dy &= \int_{0}^1\int_{y-1}^{1-y}xy^2\,dx\,dy\\
&= \int_0^1y^2\left(\frac{(1-y)^2 - (y-1)^2}{2}\right)\,dy\\
&= \int_0^1 y^2\left(\frac{0}{2}\right)\,dy = 0.
\end{align*}$$